# Spark levenshtein left join on string, match one data then break

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

```
val resultDF = todoDF.join(sourceDF,
      functions.levenshtein(sourceDF.col("string_right"),todoDF.col("string_left")) <= 3
      && sourceDF.col("string_right") =!= todoDF.col("string_left"),
      "left_outer")

resultDF.show()
```

The result shows that there are mutiple same `string_left`, which means Spark loop all the `string_right` for each `string_left`.

Could `string_left` match one `string_right` and then break, then the next `string_left` begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to decrease the candidates.

Using the first 2-4 characters of the join-string as `key_left` and `key_right`. Then join on the key.

At last compute the levenshtein distance for each row of the joined result.